# How to output sets in Gremlin through Orientdb REST API?

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

In my project, I'm sending Gremlin scripts via the REST API of Orientdb.
I'm having problem returning the values inside sets collected during the graph traversal.

I have  a simple Graph setup.

```
User-- FollowsMovies -- > Movies
User-- FollowsActors -- > Actors


u= g.v('12:1');
following= [] as Set;
u.as('x').out('FollowsMovies').aggregate(following).back('x').out('FollowsActors').aggregate(following);
return following.toString();
```

however, the script returns nothing. If I ask for size of 'following', it returns 0, although it is not supposed to be empty.

I Tried the same code on the gremlin console and it worked as expected. Can anyone suggest how to correctly output elements of a set?

Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `iterate()`at the end of your query.

See: http://gremlindocs.com/#methods/pipe-iterate